# Assistance in understanding an assignment involving Trees and Colour Propagation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given an assignment as outlined below

We are asked to design a tree capable of storing a certain propagating colour. Which colour is propagated is determined by the colours sorted in its subtree. There is a hierarchy of colours, and an ordering exists to determine which is the dominating colour that will be propagated. This tree is used to do some elemental property checking to run some "what if" scenarios.
The tree contains a colour propagation, based on the hierarchy:

1. RED (R)
2. GREEN (G)
3. BLUE (B)
4. CYAN (C)
5. YELLOW (Y)

With **RED** being the strongest colour.

The tree:

```
   Y
  / \
 C   G
  \   \
  R    Y
```

Will produce the propagations:

```
   R
  / \
 R   G
  \   \
  R    Y
```

I am extremely confused on what this means, could someone please assist me in understanding this

Answer (score 1):

You can define a recursive method to perform the propagation in the class that represents each node of the tree:

```
colors = ['R', 'G', 'B', 'C', 'Y'][::-1]
class Color:
   def __init__(self, c, children=[]):
      self.c, self.children = c, children
   def propagate(self):
      #check if node has any child colors while recursively propagating
      if [n.propagate() for n in self.children]:
         #find maximum child node (based on ranking)
         m = max(self.children, key=lambda x:colors.index(x.c)).c
         if colors.index(m) > colors.index(self.c):
            #if maximum child node is higher ranking than the node color itself, reassign the current node color to the maximum child
            self.c = m
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.c}, {self.children})'

tree = Color('Y', [Color('C', [Color('R')]), Color('G', [Color('Y')])])
tree.propagate()
```

Output:

```
Color(R, [Color(R, [Color(R, [])]), Color(G, [Color(Y, [])])])
```